# LyX table-wide settings and multi-page table error

Tags: tables

I have a large 8x8 matrix with text in it that runs over 8 pages when the table is portrait. But when I try to specify the rotation angle in the table-wide settings tab I get a `missing \endgroup inserted` error with `! Paragraph ended before \LT@entry was complete`.

And if I disable the multi-page table option the document compiles but obviously the table is chopped on the first page.

Running LyX 2.2.3 and MiKTeX 2.9 with most recent updates.

I should note that I am using LyX and cannot modify much of this source code. I'm also trying to include this document as an appendix, hence why I need the table rotated, not the document rotated.

---

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Analysis Grid}

\begin{longtable}[l]{|>{\centering}p{1cm}|>{\centering}p{3cm}|>{\centering}p{2cm}|>{\centering}p{3cm}|>{\centering}p{3cm}|>{\centering}p{3cm}|>{\centering}p{3cm}|>{\centering}p{3cm}|}
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Code} & {\scriptsize{}Observation} & {\scriptsize{}Value} & {\scriptsize{}Relevance} & {\scriptsize{}Theory} & {\scriptsize{}Data} & {\scriptsize{}Variables and Units} & Links\tabularnewline
\hline 
\endhead
\hline 
{\tiny{}A} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\tiny{}B} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\tiny{}C} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\tiny{}D} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\tiny{}E} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\tiny{}E} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\tiny{}G} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{longtable}

\label{appendix3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: to help you we need to see, what you do so far. so, please provide small but complete document which will show your problem. help us to help you! welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hi @Zarko, when I try to compile the master document (which includes other chapters) I keep getting errors despite having made the inclusions in the preamble of the master document.
 \newgeometry
                {margin=25mm}\begin{landscape}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: @Ezzat, from your comment follows, that reported error is not generated by my MWE (which you apparently not use. (you not vote nor accept it), so I cant help you further.

Comment: @Zarko I did use your code as per your previous post. The document that has that code compiles just fine. The errors come up when I try to compile the master document that contains that rotate table document among others.

Comment: @Ezzat, than source of your troubles is not my MWE (as I already said). Actually, I solve your problem asked in question, so I expect that you will vote for it (by clicking on upper pen at top left side of answer) and accept them (by clicking on check mark (also at top left side of answer) and for **new problem** ask **new question** (not in comment here where is not visible to people who can help you).

Answer (score 1):

your table is to wide (21 cm) to be fit in page even if it is rotated. For rotated long table I suggest to use `lscape` package and its `landscape` orientation with changed page layout:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array, 
            makecell, % <-- added
            longtable}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}% <-- added
\usepackage{lscape}% <-- added
\usepackage{ragged2e}% <-- added

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% for text filler

\begin{document}

\chapter{Analysis Grid}
\lipsum[1-3]

\newgeometry{margin=25mm}% <-- added
\begin{landscape}% <-- added
\footnotesize% <-- added
\begin{longtable}[l]{|c% <-- changged
                     |P{3cm}|P{2cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}|}
\hline
\thead[b]{Code} & \thead[b]{Observation} & \thead[b]{Value} & \thead[b]{Relevance} & \thead[b]{Theory} & \thead[b]{Data} & \thead[b]{Variables\\ and Units} & \thead[b]{Links}             \\% <-- changed
\hline
\endhead
\hline
A  & \lipsum*[11] &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
B  & \lipsum*[11]  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
C  & \lipsum*[11]  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
D  & \lipsum*[11]  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
E  & \lipsum*[11]  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
E  & \lipsum*[11]  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
G  & \lipsum*[11]  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\label{appendix3}
\end{landscape}% <-- added
\restoregeometry% <-- added

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, I added packages:

- `makecell` and use its macro `thead` for column headers
- `ragged2e` for smart adjusting longer text in cells
- define new column type `P` which alows to use `\\` instead `\tabularnewline`
- package `lipsum` is used for generating dummy text in cells (tat table can span over eight pages).

**Note:**
`lansdcape` environment always start on new page.

Is this what you looking for?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. that's exactly how I would like it to appear. I can't figure out how to insert back the code into the document?

Comment: @Ezzat, as it is :-). in preamble of your document add new (added) packages, and in document your table with `\newgeometry{margin=25mm}\begin{landscape}` on beginning and  `\end{landscape}\restoregeometry` after the end of the table.

Comment: I forgot to ask- getting some weird behaviour. Some text in the cells is spaced at 1.5 instead of single (that's in the same cell). Any idea why?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ZhkBV

Comment: @Ezzat, for new problem it wold be better to ask new question with MWE, which reproduce your problem. ON this wav more people will see it and can help you. If you liked answer, you can vote it and even accept :)